# Create a NEXT and PREVIOUS to display records of JSON data

Tags: javascript, php

I have created a JSON file with the following fields:
Name| Age| Gender
There are total 50 records. Here I require 2 functionalities.

1. Display 10 records per page and
2. Cycle through records using NEXT and PREV buttons only.

I tried searching but everyone has tried with mysql and javascript which I have tried and got so many errors.
So, can anyone help me with this.

This is the php code I've used:

```
    <?php
    
    $emp = file_get_contents('employee.json');
    $emp = json_decode($emp,true);
    $page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
    $limit = 5; 
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    $total_items = count($emp['employee']); 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit);
    $array = array_splice($emp['employee'], $offset, $limit);

    for($j=1;$j<=$total_pages;$j++) {
        echo "<span><a href='json.php?page=$j'>$j</a></span>";
    }
    
    foreach($emp['employee'] as $emps){
    ?>
    <tr>
    
    
    <td><?php   echo $emps['name'];  ?></td> 
    <td><?php   echo $emps['gender'];  ?></td> 
    <td><?php   echo $emps['designation'];  ?></td> 
    
    </tr>   
        <?php
}

     ?>
```

Here I have encountered the following errors:

1. All the records are displayed in the page and even it is repeating in the next page.
2. Here I wanted to insert the Next and previous buttons instead of the page numbers.

This is the result I have got till now:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4gq4.png)

Comment: What code have you written, where are you stuck? Stack Overflow is not a coding service. What about passing your php script 2 parameters - the number of records you'd like displayed and the index of the first one?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question as per your request. Can you help me now @enhzflep?

Comment: _“All the records are displayed”_ - of course they are, because you are simply doing `foreach($emp['employee'] as $emps)`, you have not implemented _any_ limitation or selection of _specific_ records out of the full set here.

Comment: _“Here I wanted to insert the Next and previous buttons instead of the page numbers.”_ - and what is stopping you? Obviously, instead of that `for` loop that creates a link for all page numbers from 1 to $total_pages, you need to create one link for `$page-1`, and one for `$page+1`. And implement a check, so that you do _not_ output the “previous” link, if `$page-1` is less than 1, and not the “next” link, if `$page+1` is greater than $total_pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can build on. Of course you can't just copy and paste - that makes it harder to be sure that the required understanding has sunk-in! I've written it quick-n-dirty. You can extract the required logic AND add some error checking...

**data.json**

```
[
    {"name": "name1", "gender": "male", "title": "junior dev"},
    {"name": "name2", "gender": "female", "title": "junior dev"},
    {"name": "name3", "gender": "unicorn", "title": "junior dev"},
    {"name": "name4", "gender": "toaster", "title": "junior dev"},
    {"name": "name5", "gender": "pineapple", "title": "junior dev"}
]
```

**showResults.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
thead{
    background-color: #888;
    color: #fff;
}
th{
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
td{
    padding: 4px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $filename = "data.json";
    $rawData = file_get_contents($filename);
    $dataArray = json_decode($rawData,true);
    
    $pageNum = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['page']))
        $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
    
    $recordCount = count($dataArray);
    $itemsPerPage = 2;
    $maxPage = floor($recordCount / $itemsPerPage) - 1;
?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>title</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
    $firstRecordIndex = $pageNum * $itemsPerPage;
    for ($index = $firstRecordIndex; $index < ($firstRecordIndex+$itemsPerPage); ++$index)
    {
        if (isset($dataArray[$index]))
        printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", 
                $dataArray[$index]['name'], 
                $dataArray[$index]['gender'], 
                $dataArray[$index]['title']);
    }
?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a href='showResults.php?page=<?php print( max(0,$pageNum-1));?>'>Prev</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @CodingLuv - You're welcome. Glad it's helpful. :)